# Angular - вывод значений

Tags: node.js, angular

Есть такой код:

```
     const users = await this.manager.createQueryBuilder(UserEntity, "user")
        .select('user.name as name, user.gender as gender, user.roleId as role, user.organizationId as organization')
        .where("user.organizationId = :organizationId", { organizationId: args.organizationId })
        .orderBy("user.createDate")
        .getRawMany()
```

В users идут все значение из select-а. Как вычислить значение конкретного поля, например users.role. В самом коде пишу так, console.log(users.role), дает ошибку "Property 'role' does not exist on type 'any[]'."

Comment: getRawMany возвращает массив. `.roles` есть у _элемента_ этого массива

Comment: и как его вывести? Не подскажете?

Comment: `console.log(users)`

Comment: Я так делал, как Вы сказали, но он мне возвращает массив. А мне нужен конкретное значение из этого массива. Как сделать?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/array и https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods

Comment: Спасибо за консультацию. По методам массива, я выведу определенное значение массива. Например: users[0].role. А мне нужно вывести все значение этого поля всего масссива. Как сделать?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/array#perebor-elementov и https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#perebor-foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var roles= users.map(a => a.role);

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: на самом деле нужно что-то вроде `users.map((user) => user.roles || []).flat()`